# How create new .NET Core SPA Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been learning Angular and using

> dotnet new angular

to create new applications. But this gives the error

> : here no templates matched the input template name :

angular
 command can create the and show the spa template

> dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*

But it not showing the options for angular, any solutions?

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T37wx.png)

Comment: Angular or AngularJS? You're using both tags.

Comment: Angular         , only , ,,

Comment: So why don't you use [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)? That's what it's made for. `ng new AngularProject`.

Comment: Angular with asp.net  core

Comment: Run `dotnet new -l` to see what templates you have installed.

Comment: i want to create a spa template for asp.net core with angular using command

Comment: All the template is installed except angular

Comment: What version of dotnet are you using ?

Comment: version of dotnet 4.0

Comment: I meant the SDK version.

Comment: For info I had the same problem after upgrading from VS15.2 to VS15.3. dotnet no longer lists Angular on the SPA template, Auerelia, Knockout and Vue are still available.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

@anserk, was right. You use outdated .NET Core 2.0 SDK.

1) If you use VS Code:
you should install latest [.NET Core 2.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) and create project via dotnet new

> dotnet new angular

2) If you use VS 2017:
you should update your VS from Visual Studio setup bootstrapper and you will be able to create template via file->new->project->angular or via dotnet new

OUTDATED:
Use yo generator to create new .NET Core SPA angular project

1) install [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)

2) open cmd

3) run `npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa`

4) move to project folder

5) run `yo aspnetcore-spa`

6) Choose Angular project

7) Open project file in project folder to use Visual studio or open folder to use VS Code

[more info](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices)

Comment: yo aspnetcore-spa commnad run but i cannot create angular option in spa template

Comment: @Nasir, any error? or whats you get when run this yo aspnetcore-spa?

Comment: D:\Angular\Work>yo aspnetcore-spa
## Please use "dotnet new" templates instead

As of .NET Core 2.0, it's no longer necessary to use Yeoman to create new Single
-Page Application projects.

Using the .NET Core 2.0 SDK, you can run any of the following commands in an emp
ty directory, without needing to install any external packages first:

    * dotnet new angular
    * dotnet new react
    * dotnet new redux

Comment: Or, if you want to create an Aurelia, Knockout, or Vue application, you should r
un dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::* first. This will ad
d aurelia, knockout, and vue templates to dotnet new.

### This Yeoman generator is DEPRECATED

Please don't use generator-aspnetcore-spa to create new projects. Its output is
outdated and no longer maintained. Instead, use dotnet new as described above (o
r if you're on Windows and use Visual Studio, you can just use File->New Project
 to create Angular, React, or React+Redux projects).

Comment: @Nasir, your IDE will be VS2017 or VS Code?